# Page Object Model Practices

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

I am building a testing framework for a website using Page Object Model with Selenium

I am thinking that in general if I have two pages with the exact user controls and functions but different URLs I should create one father page class that has two classes inheriting from it.
But what if I have the same two pages with different locators for controls? what do you think? do you think that creating a totally separate class for every page will be a good practice? or is there a way to let the children classes override locators? knowing that I am using PageFactory.

Here is an example

```
 public class Header 
    {
    [FindsBy(How = How.ClassName, Using = "logout_button")]
    public IWebElement BtnLogout { get; set; }

    public Header()
    {
     PageFactory.InitElements(Browser.Driver, this);
    }

    public void Logout()
    {
        this.BtnLogout.Click();

    }

}

public class SecondHeader
{
    [FindsBy(How = How.ClassName, Using = "logout")]
    public IWebElement BtnLogout { get; set; }

    public Header()
    {
     PageFactory.InitElements(Browser.Driver, this);
    }

    public void Logout()
    {
        this.BtnLogout.Click();

    }

}
```

Comment: Use inheritance, build Parent(father) page and pass the locator value as param to get the control. HTH.

Comment: how to pass locators when using  [FindsBy(How = How.method, Using = value)]

Comment: Can you please quickly post the sample code here?

Comment: @MuralidharanDeenathayalan Post updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
public class Header 
    {
    [FindsBy(How = How.ClassName, Using = "logout_button")]
    public virtual IWebElement BtnLogout { get; set; }

    public Header()
    {
     PageFactory.InitElements(Browser.Driver, this);
    }

    public void Logout()
    {
        this.BtnLogout.Click();

    }

}

public class SecondHeader: Header
{
    [FindsBy(How = How.ClassName, Using = "logout")]
    public overidde IWebElement BtnLogout { get; set; }
}
```